# All audio and video files play faster and have no sound

Tags: sound, video

as the title says, all video and audio files, whether from youtube or some other web site or locally from my pc, play around 6x faster and there is no sound at all. I didn't preform any updates or software changes, the only possible cause would be running (trying to run) System Testing application. I didn't have a particular reason to run it I was just curious. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4. I viewed some similar posts to mine on different forums, as well as this one, and they didn't provide a solution. If any other info is needed please ask, I will provide it as soon as possible. Thanks in advance. Cheers!